# Read till EOF but exec every line upto the \n

Tags: c, system-calls

Using just System Calls, how do you read a file upto the EOF and in the process execute every line in the program, upto end of line. 
Every line in my file, will have a program name that has to be executed.

```
 size_t fd1 = open("inputfile.txt", O_RDWR);
 char buf1[BUFFSIZE];
 while(read(fd1,buf1,10) != EOF) 
 {   
      if(fd1[MAXDATA] == "\n")

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a program with similar functionality recently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
#define LINEMAXSIZE 2000
void main(int argvc,char** argv)
{
int filedesc=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE]; 

char expression[LINEMAXSIZE]; //the line
int exprindex=0;        //line index

int count=read(filedesc,buffer,sizeof(buffer));//read bytes

while(count!=EOF)
      {
            int i=0;
            while(i<count)
            {
            char c=buffer[i];
            if(c=='\n')
            {
                expression[exprindex++]='\0';
                char* line=strdup(expression);//create a new instance of the string
                system(line); //execute the line 
                exprindex=0;//set line index to 0
            }
            else
            {
                   expression[exprindex++]=c;

                if(exprindex>=LINEMAXSIZE)
                {
                printf("Line Max length reached\n");
                }

            }

        i++;
        }


        count=read(filedesc,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you do when you reach the end of line? i dont get it.

Comment: i create a new instance of the line using strdup, than execute it with system,finally i set the index of the line to 0

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename", "r");
char *line = NULL;
size_t length = 0;
char buf[1024];
do
{
    line = fgetline(f, &length);
    if (line)
    {
        strncpy(buf, line, length);
        buf[length] = '\0';
        system(buf);
    }
} while (line);
fclose(f);
```

Please note also:

1. in production code, error checking will be needed, since fgetline() doesn't distinguish between error and EOF, and returns NULL in both cases.
2. It's potentially dangerous to just read out commands from a file and execute them. One can insert malicious code and make it executed.
3. I use a buffer of 1024 bytes for the sake of simplicity, but IRL you'll have to do bound-checking and/or dynamic memory allocation in order to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: don't wanna use..fgetline or fopen. Just system calls.

Comment: like.. for fopen, I just want to use open. for fgetline, i just want to use..read(). Basically, from man 2 page of linux.